# Arrays.asList() интересное утверждение в Java OCP книге, которую не могу понять

Tags: java, массивы, list

В книге Oracle-Certified-Professiona-Java-SE-8-Programmer-Exam-1Z0-809.pdf
написано такое утверждение:

> The java.util.Arrays class has a useful method named asList() method that returns a fixed-size list. Here
>   is an interesting aspect about the returned List object: you cannot add or remove elements but you can
>   modify the object returned by the asList() method! Also, the modifications you make through the List are
>   reflected in the original array

В смысле, как  я понял, подразумевается, что из синтезированного листа через Arrays.asList нет возможности добавлять или удалять элементы.

Но почему не разрешено добавлять новые элементы? Интересно, почему обычно List дает возможность добавлять элементы но в такой ситуации не дает. Это разве не может стать причиной трудно уловимых багов?

```
Double [] temperatureArray = {31.1, 30.0, 32.5, 34.9, 33.7, 27.8};
List<Double> temperatureList = Arrays.asList(temperatureArray);
temperatureList.add(5D); 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
    at package3.UtilitiesTest.main(UtilitiesTest.java:44)
```

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Comment: Не разрешено добавлять, т.к. список этот - копия массива, а у него нельзя менять длину. Если бы он не был полной копией (т.е. изменения в списке не отражались бы на массиве, то и добавление/удаление ничего бы не ломало). А так да - если не знать этих особенностей, то баги гарантированы. Сам с этим сталкивался)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб точнее сказать, что это _представление_ массива. Именно поэтому изменение элемента списка приводит к изменению соответствующего элемента массива.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я не уверен какой тут термин лучше употребить, засим что в голову пришло то и использовал)

Comment: Ну я как то понял что это связано с тем, что сам массив имеет фиксированную длину. До того как я сегодня прочел это утверждение (ну то что выше в вопросе указал) - я всегда думал, что этот метод преобразует из массива список list. И следовательно, так как скажем добавлены 3 элемента, тогда по идее в консоле в аналогии выше кода код должен был добавить элемент на 3-ем индексе (так как 0,1 и 2 индексы уже заняты). Думал, что элементы по любому должны добавляться - так как List по идее создана именно для этой цели (ну не только для этой но все же), чтобы уметь менять свой размер/длину.

Comment: Добавлю еще один интересный момент, решил увидеть что написано в методе asList, кликнул а там в теле метода такое " return new ArrayList<>(a); " ... и опять тупик кратко говоря.

Comment: Может всему виновник, выше аннотация "@SafeVarargs" ? иначе уже не знаю на чем опираться, чтобы понять, откуда растут ноги данного интересного случая (я про свой вопрос выше, если что)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) скорее создан для удобства вызова функций, которые принимают коллекции на вход. Т.е., если изначально имеется *массив*, и его надо передать в функцию как *коллекцию*, то следует использовать указанный метод. Т.к. он создан для "удобства", то он должен быть максимально быстр, потому внутри не делается копии массива, а используется исходно переданный. Отсюда интересный побочный эффект: если вызвать метод [set(int, E)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)), то также изменится и исходный массив.

Также отсюда получается и другой эффект, что нельзя добавить в коллекцию новый элемент, т.к. массивы в java имеют неизменный размер.

Что касательно ***трудноуловимых*** багов. Как известно, одной из причин появления **Java** на свет, стала слишком большая сложность C++ и среды вокруг C++: препроцессоры над текстом, а не над синтаксическим деревом, малая функциональность базовой библиотеки, множество стилей/библиотек для написания кода со сбором мусора и т.д. Поэтому в java очень много чего выкинули для максимального упрощения. К примеру в java нет возможности явного указания, что переданный в функцию объект нельзя изменять внутри этой функции. В C++ для этого был/есть ***const***. Как оказалось позднее, это было ***большое упущение***, и многие другие языки научились на этой ошибке. К примеру, в **Kotlin** разделили java-интерфейс [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) на [Collection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html) и [MutableCollection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-collection/index.html), в **Rust** существует модификатор **mut** и т.д.

Для того, чтобы хоть как-то облегчить отлов этих багов, придумали бросать из метода, который не должен быть вызван, исключение вида [UnsupportedOperationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html). Но, это скорее лечение последствий, а не причины.

Также, из-за этих *особенностей* проектирования, Java постоянно подвергается критике.